# MATLAB: Using genpath with partial paths

Tags: matlab, path

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── root            
│   ├── DATA                
│   │   ├── GLOBAL          
│   ├── project1            
│   │   ├── branches
│   │   │   └── dev
│   │   │       └── project.m       
│   │   └── trunk       
│   │       └── project.m
```

How would I **elegantly** go about adding DATA/GLOBAL to the path from both project.m files?

Essentially, I'm looking to make `genpath` work for partial paths. `exist('DATA/GLOBAL')` returns 7 (a directory was found), but `genpath('DATA/GLOBAL')` returns '' (no path generated).

Comment: Your working directory (i.e. `pwd`) is in dev direcotry i guess?

Comment: +1 for the nice illustration of the directory tree ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `regex` to look for the part in `pwd` that all `project.m` should have in common is a fairly robust way:

```
P = regexp(pwd, ['^.*root' filesep], 'match');

if isempty(P)
    error('project:globaldir_missing',...
        'Could not find global data directory.');
end

newPath = [P{1} 'DATA' filesep 'GLOBAL'];
if ~exist(newPath , 'dir')
    error('project:pathing_error',...
        'Global data directory does not seem to exist.');
end

genpath(newPath);
```

By using `filesep` you make it independent of OS specifics, e.g., this will work on any OS.

Note that you create a dependency on the specific directory tree of your project, but well, such is the MATLAB way.

Comment: I'd implemented a similar solution (using `dir` instead of regex) and that also required the directory to be called 'root'. I wish there was a way around that, as it caused someone I was working with a serious headache, but at least the error messages should point them in the right direction. Thanks!